# What does [] mean in #{msgs[...]}

Tags: jsf, el, braces

I found this in some JSF page.

```
<h:outputText styleClass="resultLetter" value="#{msgs['result'.concat(searchResults.paginator.pageItems.rowIndex+1)]}" />
```

I'm confused and when I googled I didn't really find anything about the syntax with having `[]` and then even the `''` with `concat()` in a value expression.

Could anyone be so kind and explain to me what happens here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
[]
```

operator is a shortcut for

```
java.util.Map#get(Object key)
```

and, in your case, `key` is a `String` made up out of `'result'` and `searchResults.paginator.pageItems.rowIndex+1`.

For internationalization (i18n) bundles, the `[]` operator is often used to get a translation for the given key as specified in the appropriate bundle files.